# %~z is ignored in a batch file for loop

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

The first of these two works, the second gives nothing :

```bat
FOR /f %%a in ('dir C:\ /b') do (echo %%a) 
FOR /f %%a in ('dir C:\ /b') do (echo %%~za)
```

The first of these two works, the second gives nothing:

```bat
FOR /f "tokens=5 delims= " %%a in ('dir C:\') do (echo %%a)
FOR /f "tokens=5 delims= " %%a in ('dir C:\') do (echo %%~za)
```

The first of these two works, the second gives nothing:

```bat
FOR /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir C:\') do (echo %%a)
FOR /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir C:\') do (echo %%~za)
```

The same happens in the cmd.

Other modifiers work, for example: `%%~fa, %%~nxa, %%~pna`, e.t.c.
When `z` is included with other modifiers, `%%a` is modified according to the other modifiers, `z` has no effect.

Comment: Do you have actual files in `C:\ ` or just directories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `~z` modifier returns the size of the file which is referenced by the `FOR`'s meta variable.
For it to work the meta variable (`%%a`) must point to an existing file and the file must accessible from the current directory.
If `%%a` is an absolute path to the file (e.g. `C:\MyFile.txt`) then it doesn't matter from which directory the `FOR` command is executed, But when it is a relative path (e.g. `MyFile.txt`) then it will attempt to find the file `MyFile.txt` relative to the current directory and query its size.

`dir /b` outputs the file names only, not the full path to the files, So the behavior of the `~z` modifier depends on your current working directory. (`dir /s /b` returns full paths but it outputs files in all subdirectories as well)

For instance if you change the current directory to `C:\` before executing the `FOR` loop, then it will produce the expected result:

```
cd /D C:\
for /F "delims=" %%A in ('dir C:\ /b /a-d') do (echo %%~zA)
```

This is true for other modifiers as well (`~f`, `~d` , `~p`), while they seem to work and output something, but depending on the context, the value they return may not be what you expect, because the full path(`~f`) or the drive letter (`~d`) is calculated based on the current working directory.

That was the description for why it is the way it is.

But if you don't need to query the size of the hidden files, then there is a better way for obtaining the file sizes inside a particular directory by using the bare `FOR` command which does not depend on the current working directory.

```
for %%A in (C:\*) do echo %~zA
```

Comment: In all MS CMD.exe documentation, including the `for /?` help screen, the `%%a` part is called _replaceable parameter_. Why do you call it _meta variable_? I never have seen this term in any _official_ Batch file documentation... IMHO is better to use the original terminology.

Comment: I think this is probably the first time I used the term `meta` to address the `FOR` variables. I'm not a fan of this term, I just saw that it has been used by some fellow members of [DosTips](https://www.dostips.com/) to seemingly avoid confusion with environment variables, and it has been used plenty of times here at SO too, so I used something that might be more familiar to the readers. Actually the term `replaceable parameter` is used only once in the `FOR /?` documentation to describe the `FOR` variables, the rest of the documentation uses the term `variable(s)`.

Comment: The term `replaceable parameter` just adds more confusion rather than removing it. But that's just me, anyone is welcome to edit and use a more appropriate term.

Comment: I like "meta variable" because _technically_ it's not the letter `a`, it's a representation of the ASCII value 97, which is why you can use (almost) any of the base 128 ASCII values for `for` loop variables.

Comment: @SomethingDark - Actually the 97 represents the index into an array of values, once you subtract the base point offset. So `for /f "tokens=1,2,3" %%a in ...` uses %%a index = 97-97 = 0, %%b index = 98-97 = 1, %%c index = 99-97 = 2. But the 97 is really a Unicode code point, not an ASCII code point. Of course the ASCII code values match the Unicode code points, but you are not restricted to ASCII values! See Aacini's DosTips thread [Using many "tokens=..." in FOR /F command in a simple way](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7703). There is a lot to read, but it is worth it.

Comment: Thanks @dbenham. I saw that post a while ago; I guess I misremembered it.

Comment: If you carefully read the `for /F` help screen you'll realize that _replaceable parameter_ refers to the `%variable` part in the FOR description, and that the `variable` describe the _letter_ that is used in such a part. Of course, everyone may have a favorite term. I just question: why not use the term that appears in the original documentation? If we use what seems to be _popular_ then we could aid to spread bad practices, particularly in the case of Batch files!  @SomethingDark

Answer (score 0):

sst wrote: "change the current directory"

That solved it.

sst wrote: "true for other modifiers as well (~f, ~d , ~p)"

True for those.  Curiously unnecessary for ~n and ~x.